# Migrating code using eclipse

Tags: apex, eclipse

We are trying to migrate code from our developing org to another org.We have been successful with migrating objects and static resources using eclipse. when we try to migrate code we get an error of the type "entity not defined" as in the developing org we had a managed package with the prefix "omo" and were referencing the object in the class "omo__object__c" whereas in the new instance no such prefix exists

Is there any way by which we can migrate the code without removing the prefix name?

Comment: You will have to remove the prefix. The target org don't know about that Namespace.

Comment: Before deploy code (start the deploy wizard in Eclipse), open your class (meta data) and remove references to "omo" package. Then push changes to your new org.